# Show message/image overlay on every page in site (using web.config NOT jQuery)

Tags: asp.net

About 5 years ago I used a asp.net control to show an image in the corner of every page of a site (it was a beta sticker for a new version).

I'm keen to do this again (for the internal, pre-live version of sites) - however I don't want to alter the content of the site code to do this - definitely no jQuery on every page or anything.

Does anyone know/remember how this was done. I seem to remember just adding either a module or, more likely, a configSection entry to load something. This was nice because you can just enable it for certain sites (your test, prelive etc) without worrying it's going to carry over to live.

Comment: Are you looking at something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734787/asp-net-conditional-markup-rendering-according-to-web-config-key)? Or a way to _automatically_ render content from `web.config`? Sounds like the latter, but just in case... :)

Comment: Hi, no it is the latter. As I remember it, a single added DLL reference and a web.config key with the image url was enough to overlay a nice image in the top corner of every page automatically. Ideal for Test/PreLive/Beta site instances...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post discusses using Http Modules & Response Filters to alter the output of a page

You could search for an empty div in the output and write something to that.

http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters

Answer (score 0):

See: [Can i add a footer to multiple .net applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868668/can-i-add-a-footer-to-multiple-net-applications)

Juts add a filter module.